# PHP MySQL LOAD DATA - exclude duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Currently I'm using the following to import a CSV file in to a table.

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'list.csv'
     INTO TABLE pupils
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ( -- Field List -- )
eof;

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
  echo "Data Imported successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error importing data: " . $conn->error;
}
```

`-- Field List --` is a comma separated list of fields.

This works well and imports the data from the CSV file in to the table.

I've got a new CSV to import and there are going to be some entries that already exist in the database. During the import is it possible to check if a entry already exists ?

My Database has a field called `remote ip` which will be unique for each entry. Is there anyway to check if it exists and it it does don't import that row from the CSV ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `LOAD DATA INFILE` does exactly what it says.  You will have to remove the duplicates separately.

Comment: Thanks. I'll clean the data before importing it.